# EditText Field Create Last Name When User Enter a Space

Tags: android, arrays, string

EditText Field When user enter spaces, string converted two arrays . More Clearly ,
When i enter `"Amiyo Biswas"` . `Amiyo` will be `first name` & `Biswas` will be `last name` .I tried . Created Array for getting position 0[first name]& 1[last name].How to check space there .

May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?Maybe this question too basic, but i did't find any suitable solution.Please Help me out.

Here is my code under `Textwatcher` :

```
 public final TextWatcher unspTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence m, int start, int count, int after)
    {

    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence m, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        EditText UNSP =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserNameToSIGNUP);
        String UserFullName=UNSP.getText().toString().trim();
        UNSP.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#26AB69"));

        String[] texts = new String[2];



        texts[0] = UNSP.getText().toString();
        texts[1] = UNSP.getText().toString();

        String check=texts[0]+texts[1];

        if(check.length()==2)

        {
            UNSP.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#26AB69"));
           // UserFullName = UserFullName.replace(" ", "+");

           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You cant Press back button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{

            UNSP.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        }

    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable m)
    {

    }

};
```

Comment: Its unclear. Do u want to split string to array by detecting space OR u want to detect space entered by user in textwatcher?

Comment: Use UserFullName.split(" ");

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText UNSP =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserNameToSIGNUP);
String UserFullName=UNSP.getText().toString().trim();
String[] arr=UserFullName.split(" ");

String fname=arr[0];
String lname=arr[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java `String.split` method

Example:

```
String input= "Amiyo Biswas";
String[] parts = input.split(" ");
String firstName= parts[0]; // Amiyo String 
String secondName = parts[1]; //Biswas
```

Be aware of multiple spaces in the input